# Python: Iterate Over Year and Month in DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1:
                  A    B 
Date
01/01/2020        2    4
02/01/2020        6    8


df2:
                  A    B
Date
01/01/2020        5    10
```

I want to get the following:

```
df3:
                  A    B 
Date
01/01/2020        10   40
02/01/2020        30   80
```

What I want is to multiply the column entries based on year and month in DatetimeIndex. But I'm not sure how to iterate over datetime.

Comment: Hi!! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

use `to_numpy()`:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame(df1.to_numpy()*df2.to_numpy(),index=df1.index,columns=df1.columns)
```

output of `df3`:

```
             A  B
Date        
01/01/2020  10  40
02/01/2020  30  80
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need `reindex`

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index,dayfirst=True)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index,dayfirst=True)
df2.index = df2.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
df1[:] *= df2.reindex(df1.index.strftime('%Y-%m')).values

df1
Out[529]: 
             A   B
Date              
2020-01-01  10  40
2020-01-02  30  80
```